# Edit form in rails - No route matches [PUT]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, haml

I have a form to create tasks.

Controllers:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @projects = Project.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new
    @project.title = project_params[:title]
    @project.user_id = current_user.id

    if @project.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = @project.errors.to_a
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @project = current_user.projects.find_by(params[:id])

    flash[:error] = @project.errors.to_a unless @project.destroy

    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def edit
    @project = current_user.projects.find_by(params[:id])
    render :edit
  end



  def update
  end  

  private

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :projects
  root 'projects#index'
end
```

new.html.haml

```
.create_project_form
    = form_with model: @project, url: "/projects", method: :post do |form|
        = form.text_field :title, { placeholder: 'New Project' }
        = form.submit 'Create project'
```

I can create task, but I can't update it.

edit.html.haml

```
.edit_project_form
    = form_with model: @project, url: "/projects", method: :put do |form|
        = form.text_field :title, { placeholder: 'Edit' }
        = form.submit 'Update project'
```

When I submit my form, I have an error - No route matches [PUT] "/projects"

As i understand i have to pass an id somewhere at

```
= form_with model: @project, url: "/projects", method: :put do |form|
```

But i can't find an appropriate method to do it
Help please

Answer (score 1):

Your edit form is submitting to the wrong path. In Rails you update a resource by sending a PATCH request to the member route `/projects/:id`. Rails switched from using [PUT to PATCH back in 2012](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/26/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/) but still generates  PUT routes for legacy reasons.

You  don't even need to explicitly provide the path and method here in the first place. Instead use convention over configuration Rails style:

```
# app/views/projects/_form.html.rev
= form_with(model: @project) 
  #...
```

Rails will figure out the correct route and method by checking if the record had been saved.

And [use a partial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) instead of repeating the same form in your new and edit views.